# How to return an arrayList of Strings

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I'm trying to return an ArrayList of userData which is the UserNames of all the users in the Database. I keep getting errors trying to return the ArrayList. Can anyone help?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class readCSV
{
    List<String[]> userData = new ArrayList<String[]> ();
    public void checkLogin() throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File("C:/Users/Sean/Documents/Programming assigment/Users.csv");
            BufferedReader bufRdr  = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));      
            String lineRead = bufRdr.readLine();
            while(lineRead != null)
            {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                while(lineRead != null)
                {
                    this.userData.add (lineRead.split(","));
                }
                bufRdr.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception er){
            System.out.print(er); 
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public String[] getLogin()
    {
        return userData;
    }
}
```

> Error imcompatable types

Comment: "I keep getting errors" - **always** show the errors in your question. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Where is the database? I don't see any JDBC.

Comment: public List<String[]> getLogin()

Comment: Also, for the record, `ArrayList<String[]>` is an `ArrayList` of `String` *arrays*, not of `String`s. Based on your description of the problem, you probably want to be using an `ArrayList<String>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public String[] getLogin()
```

The return type is `String[]`, and you are returning a `List<String[]>` -

```
return userData;  // userData is `List<String[]>`
```

You need to change the method signature to: -

```
public List<String[]> getLogin()
```

Comment: @user1323808.. Also follow the suggestion of Jon Skeet in comment in future. Always show where you got error. And in case of Exception, post Stack Trace. It is always helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the return type of `getLogin()` method. It returns a `List<String[]>` and  not `String[]`. Change the return type accordingly.

Comment: @istovatis.. Aww! You got a little bit late. Still you can add a little bit more description to your answer to make it an answer that can stand. :)

Comment: To add code tags around your code, you can add backticks before and after them. The key on the left side of `1` key.